# Code::Blocks debugger painfully slow on Kubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb, codeblocks

I have Kubuntu 14.10 and 15.04 installed on my four computers, all having different hardware (the oldest machine was assembbled in 2007 and the newest just a month ago. I have both 32- and 64-bit OSs installed. The amount of RAM varies from 4 to 32 GB). I have been using Code::Blocks on them for a few months, and I experience the same problem on all 4 machines: integrated debugger is painfully slow when debugging a C++ program.
After the debugger stops at a breakpoint, it takes 10 seconds to 5 minutes to step through a single line of code. And while the debugger is performing a step, one core of my CPU is loaded by GDB by 100%. And often trying to step through a line of code hangs forever. After that I have to kill GDB and the process that has been debugged.
Some time ago I updated GDB to version 7.9 (from 7.8) but this did not fix the problem. And I have no slowdown when debugging with GDB from command line, so I suspect that the problem is in the Code::Blocks debugger plugin.
I saw many complaints regarding similar problems, some of which were allegedly caused by outdated libc6-dbg (more exactly, by the fact that debug symbols were not shipped with Ubuntu and other Debian-based distributions), but reinstalling libc6-dbg did not help either.
I am afraid that after a day or two of trying to fix this problem I will give up and will switch to Eclipse or some other IDE. It looks like Code::Blocks and its debugger plugin have not been updated for a couple of years (at least, their Linux versions). So maybe I should not use Code::Blocks at all because its future is not clear (while Eclipse is likely to be in service for long time).
I wonder if anybody else experiences this problem and whether there are solutions. Overall Code::Blocks IDE looks decent and rather convenient, but this debugger problem prevents from using it for purposes other than writing code and compiling.

An update:
I ended up installing Eclipse for C++ (Luna release). It took some time to learn how to use it. It is slow, buggy, glitchy and uses a lot of RAM, but it at least allows me to debug my applications in IDE. Now I am 100% sure that the problem is in Code::Blocks debugger plugin.
I also tried NetBeans, and seems to work fine, but it is even slower than Eclipse and looks really ugly. So I am going to stick with Eclipse for now because no one seems to be willing to fix the debugger plugin in Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be with stepping through lines that declare uninitialized std::string objects. A similar (or the same) problem is described here:

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12555

The probleb with debugging in Code::Blocks was suddenly fixed when I followed these instructions:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_inspect_the_contents_of_STL_containers.3F

on how to enable pretty-printing in Eclipse CDT.
I still need to follow these instructions on my other machines to make sure they fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and turn off CodeBlock pretty-printing: `Settings->Debugger->Default->Enable Watch Scripts = Unchecked`
([Source](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Pretty_Printers))